# SQL how to create multiple row from a single row

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi I am new to SQL server 2008

I want to expand a single row to multiple rows based on another colomn,

e.g

```
date          value
7-2011         5
```

Results:

```
2011-07-01     
2011-08-01
2011-09-01
2011-10-01
2012-11-01
```

the date shoild be first day of current and next month repeated 5 times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (YourDate datetime, value int)

insert into @YourTable VALUES ('2011-7-12',5)

;WITH AllNumbers AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM AllNumbers
        WHERE Number<4
)
SELECT 
    dateadd(month,number,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,YourDate),0))
    FROM @YourTable        y
    INNER JOIN AllNumbers  a ON 1=1
```

output:

```
-----------------------
2011-07-01 00:00:00.000
2011-08-01 00:00:00.000
2011-09-01 00:00:00.000
2011-10-01 00:00:00.000
2011-11-01 00:00:00.000

(5 row(s) affected)
```

it works with multiple rows in the table, see here:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (YourDate datetime, ValueOf int)

insert into @YourTable VALUES ('2011-7-12',5)
insert into @YourTable VALUES ('2012-4-24',6)

;WITH AllNumbers AS
(
    SELECT 0 AS Number
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Number+1
        FROM AllNumbers
        WHERE Number<4
)
SELECT 
    y.ValueOf
        ,dateadd(month,number,DATEADD(month,DATEDIFF(month,0,y.YourDate),0))
    FROM @YourTable        y
    INNER JOIN AllNumbers  a ON 1=1
    ORDER BY 1,2
```

OUTPUT:

```
ValueOf     
----------- -----------------------
5           2011-07-01 00:00:00.000
5           2011-08-01 00:00:00.000
5           2011-09-01 00:00:00.000
5           2011-10-01 00:00:00.000
5           2011-11-01 00:00:00.000
6           2012-04-01 00:00:00.000
6           2012-05-01 00:00:00.000
6           2012-06-01 00:00:00.000
6           2012-07-01 00:00:00.000
6           2012-08-01 00:00:00.000

(10 row(s) affected)
```

Also, I don't have SQL Server 2008 available, so I used datetime, if you have 2008, you can use `DATE` datatype and you don't have to floor the datetime, so use this line:

```
dateadd(month,number,y.YourDate)
```

Comment: thanks however i have a table with different months and values and i would like to split by the values not a single value

Comment: Hi thanks it works but how do i dynamically select the date and the value from the table instead of setting them manually?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for? you can always add a `WHERE ValueOf=6` or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
create  function addMonths(@date date, @limit int)
returns @date_table TABLE(
myDate date
)
AS
begin
  declare @cont int
  set @cont = 1
  while (@cont <= @limit) begin
    insert into @date_table values(DATEADD(MONTH,@cont,@date))
    set @cont=@cont+1
  end

  return 
end
```

usage:

```
select * from addMonths(GETDATE(),5)
```

EDIT:

```
create table mydates(
myDate date,
inc_months int)


insert into mydates values ('01/01/2005',3)
insert into mydates values ('01/01/2006',5)


select AM.mydate 
from mydates MD cross apply addMonths(MD.mydate,MD.inc_months) AM
```

result:

```
2005-02-01
2005-03-01
2005-04-01
2006-02-01
2006-03-01
2006-04-01
2006-05-01
2006-06-01
```

Comment: you pass in @date but use GETDATE() within the function

Comment: Thanks Guys but the point is i dont want to pass the @date and the value I have to select them from onother table and do the expansion in my new table i have for example 1000 row and values does that mean i will have to pass the parameters 1000? instead of selecting them from an existing table?

Comment: @Diego thanks you are a star!! how do i add the fuction to my normal query? i have never worked with them

Comment: well, depends on your query. If you follow my example, just replace the mydates table for your table and the mydate and inc_months column by your column.

Comment: I already did thanks, One more Question though i have a date in this format: 

5-2011
when I run my query with the addMonth fuction i get this error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

how do i convert it to a date?

Comment: I meant to vote for my answer.About your question, you cant, 5-2011 is not a date, where is the third part of it?

Comment: @Diego lol, i figured it out buddy:

Convert(date,RIGHT(start,4) + '-' + REPLACE(start,'-'+RIGHT(start,4),'') + '-1' :-)