# Print out same row multiple times based on calculated value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a query that returns something similar to the following:

```
Zone    | NeededItems
===========================
209     | 5
213     | 1
216     | 1
220     | 2
218     | 1
219     | 4
215     | 1
```

The query behind it is something like:

```
SELECT
    r.Zone as Zone, r.Required - COUNT(i.Item) as NeededItems
FROM
    MyItems i
INNER JOIN
    MyRequirements r ON i.Zone = r.Zone
GROUP BY
    r.Zone, r.Required
```

Where MyItems looks like: (Value of Item doesn't matter)

```
Zone    | Item
================
209     | a
209     | b
209     | c
216     | a
220     | a
213     | z
218     | x
219     | q
219     | w
219     | e
219     | r
215     | t
```

And MyRequirements looks like:

```
Zone    | Required
======================
209     | 8
213     | 2
216     | 2
220     | 3
218     | 2
219     | 5
215     | 2
```

What I need to be able to do is print out the Zone multiple times based on the value in Needed. The value in Needed is a calculated value which is what is making this difficult (I can't just remove the count!)

So the results I am looking for is simply a list of zones, each appearing the number of times it is needed.

```
Zone    
====
209
209
209
209
209
213
216
220
220
218
219     
219
219
219
215
```

Is there any way in SQL that this can be done? Using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I've found this question which is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298487/sql-how-to-create-multiple-row-from-a-single-row . If I'm able to solve my problem based off this I'll add an answer.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is *one* way to do it - using the e1, e2 and e3 queries are not the cleanest way to do it, but it's the only way that I could manage to get it working.

One bit limitation: it only works for up to 1000 items of each (more than enough for mine.) This could be changed by editing `WHERE c<9` but be aware this is recursive so best not to have it more than what is needed.

```
WITH CTE as
(
    SELECT
        r.Zone as Zone, r.Required - COUNT(i.Item) as NeededItems
    FROM
        MyItems i
    INNER JOIN
        MyRequirements r ON i.Zone = r.Zone
    GROUP BY
        r.Zone, r.Required
),
e1(n,c ) AS
(
    SELECT 1, 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n, c + 1
        FROM e1
        WHERE c<9
), -- 10
e2(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b -- 100
),
e3(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2 -- 1000
), 
Numbers AS
(
    SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) FROM e3
)

SELECT
    Zone
FROM
    Numbers
INNER JOIN
    CTE on CTE.NeededItems >= n ORDER BY Zone
```